# How to write snap SPARQL Query when using Pellet as reasoner

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl, pellet

i learn ontologies for study purposes. Here i encontered problem when querying.
i use pellet as reasoner, because i did some swrl builts-in
here i has `class` named `resep_makanan` and i want to get all its instance
so i write

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX :<http://www.semanticweb.org/astrid/ontologies/2019/5/mpasiv2#>

SELECT ?resep_makanan
WHERE {
    ?resep_makanan rdf:type :resep_makanan.
}
ORDER BY ?resep_makanan
```

[Please click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHmXT.png)

So, how should i write it correctly?

Comment: the query is ok, there must be some other issue. Which Protege version do you use?

Comment: i used protege 5.5.0. its portable version